# How to construct free subgroup of SO(3) using Baire's Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, lie-groups, paradoxes, baire-category

I'm looking to demonstrate that there exists a free group on two generators $ G\subseteq SO(3) $ (<s>this is for homework, so hints are preferred to complete answers</s> I've turned it in now, so full answers welcome!).  I'd like to do something similar to the first answer in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49363/cheap-non-constructive-free-group-generating-rotations-for-banach-tarski) MathOverflow post as follows:

Let $A$ denote the set of all reduced words and $w\in A$.  $A$ is equinumerous with $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[x]$, hence countable; and each $w$ defines a $\tilde{w}\in C^1(SO(3)^2\to SO(3))$ via substitution.  I think, for each nontrivial $w$, the set $Z_w=\tilde{w}^{\leftarrow}(\{I_3\})$ ought to be nowhere dense.  Then I can conclude that, as $SO(3)^2$ is a complete metric space, it is Baire, so there must exist some $(x,y)\in SO(3)^2\setminus\cup_{w\in A\setminus\{e\}}{Z_w}$.  Thus $\langle x,y\rangle\subseteq SO(3)$ is free, as desired.

Now, to prove each $Z_w$ is nowhere dense: $\tilde{w}$ is continuous, so $Z_w$ is closed, so it suffices to show each $Z_w$ is interiorless.  I feel like an argument should run along the lines of the proof that any Hamel basis of an infinite-dimensional Banach space is uncountable: $Z_w$ is "like" a manifold of non-vanishing codimension.  One way to obtain such a result is the Implicit Function Theorem: we have one $SO(3)$'s worth of equations, so there should be one $SO(3)$ "perpendicular" to the solutions.

But I don't know how to show that $\tilde{w}$ has nonsingular derivative.  The nicest parameterization of $SO(3)$ seems to be the unit quaternions in polar form, but even then, I can't figure out a nice way to write the (total) derivative (considering $(\mathbb{H}_{0,\text{unit}}\times\mathbb{R})^2$ as a real 6-manifold).  The key has to lie in the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula, so that I can write a product of quaternion exponentials as a quaternion exponential of a sum, because everything above holds for $SO(2)$ parameterized by $\mathbb{C}$, except that all the "higher-order" terms of the BCH formula vanish.

So: **how do polar quaternions multiply, according to the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula?**

Comment: Do you require a proof via this approach? There are easier approaches that don't use BCH (because BCH is rather hard to use, as you've noticed)

Comment: Hi, Stella!  Of course not.  I'm ashamed to admit this, but it would suffice to figure out a "product rule" for SO(3), and I can't manage that.

Comment: So, to take a different approach, take two rotations, one around $x$ and one around $y$, by some amount α and β respectively. If this doesn't produce a free group, then there is some reduction rule, which gives rise to an equation relating α and β. Then you just have to choose two such numbers that cannot satisfy such a relation.

Comment: @Stella I think that might work.  If you write it up as an answer, I'll accept it; if not, I'll try and write it up next weekend.